# convert char* to double with max 2 places after the point

Tags: c, char, double

i'm reading tokens from file, it enters the char pointers perfectly as it comes
in the file, but after sending it to this function:

```
double CharToDouble(char *ptemp)
{
 if(ptemp != NULL)
 {
  if(ptemp[0] == '0')
   return atof(ptemp);
  else
   return atof(ptemp)/100;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

the values i'm getting in the doubles where i save this function result are like 0.6600000000001
0.280000000000000000

and stuff like that, i want it to be ecaxtly as in the char*..
it's money issues, in cents.

any idea?

Comment: FYI, to format your code highlight it and hit CTRL+K or the 101 icon, not block quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a currency, multiply by 100 and round down to an integer, so instead of 123.45, you have 12345.

Note: Float and Double are accurate only up to a certain precision (machine precision), because not every real number can be encoded in the floating point format.

When you're only interested in *output* of the correct format, you must use the correct printf command, i.e.

```
double currency_value = 9.95;
printf("Currency: %.2f", currency_value)
```

Look up "Format String" to learn more. The `%.2f` says that I want a floating point number with a fixed position after the comma (f) and that this position should be the second number after the comma (2).

Comment: but while transfering it to double with atof(char* x) it sometimes transfer the char 0.78 to the double 0.78000000000001 and that's ok, i can handle it as you explained, but sometimes it transfer the char 0.85 to the double 0.849999999999999999991 or something such that..

Comment: @Kobby: so, you need to round, not necessary "round down".  Try the math.c function `round(double)` to clean up your input.  `printf("%.2f", x)` will also round as it outputs, so 0.8499... will still be displayed as 0.85.